# How to receive data from an Arduino-based Bluetooth device in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, arduino, bluetooth

I am working on a smart white cane project. A white cane with is connected to an android device via Bluetooth and some buttons are used to issue commands to the app remotely.
For the implementation, I have used the flutter_bluetooth_serial and it has been largely successful. My problem comes to the phone receiving the command and how to set the app to be always listening for the command. The part of Arduino code to send the command is

````
{data=connection.read();
} if (digitalRead(Send_SMS==HIGH))
{connection.println(send sms");```
````

Answer (score 0):

Hello take a look at this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble) which can connect with Bluetooth devices

Answer (score 0):

here is the code to connect the Arduino Bluetooth HC-05 module with flutter app. Just use the [flutter_bluetooth_serial](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial) package. This is the only example code for controlling the servo motor rotates to 0 and 360 degrees. It also shows wether the bluetooth is connected or not. First pair the bluetooth in settings and then connect it using the flutter app.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  BluetoothConnection? _connection;
  bool _isConnected = false;
  bool isLoading = false;

  Future<void> _connectToDevice() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    final List<BluetoothDevice> devices = await FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance
        .getBondedDevices();
    final BluetoothDevice device = devices
        .firstWhere((d) => d.name == "HC-05");
    final BluetoothConnection connection =
        await BluetoothConnection.toAddress(device.address);
    setState(() {
      _connection = connection;
      _isConnected = true;
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _disconnectFromDevice() async {
    await _connection!.finish();
    setState(() {
      _connection = null;
      _isConnected = false;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _sendData(int value) async {
    if (_connection != null) {
      Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(value.toString()));
      _connection!.output.add(bytes);
      await _connection!.output.allSent;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Control Servo"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            FlutterLogo(size: 150),
            Text(
              _isConnected ? "CONNECTED" : "DISCONNECTED",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: _isConnected ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
                  fontSize: 20),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _isConnected ? () => _sendData(1) : null,
              child: const Text('Rotate 0'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _isConnected ? () => _sendData(2) : null,
              child: const Text('Rotate 360'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            isLoading
                ? const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  )
                : const SizedBox(),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed:
                  _isConnected ? _disconnectFromDevice : _connectToDevice,
              child: Text(_isConnected ? "Disconnect" : "Connect"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```